# How can I use Expand with TeXForm[HoldForm]?

Tags: latex

I want to use `Expand[(x - 7)^2 + 49]]` with `TeXForm[HoldForm` of the expression `Cos[Pi/2 + 5/(Expand[(x - 7)^2 + 49])]`. I used

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[Cos[Pi/2 + 5/(Expand[(x - 7)^2 + 49])]]]
```

I got

> \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{5}{\text{Expand}\left[(x-7)^2+49\right]}\right)

If I use

```
TeXForm[Cos[Pi/2 + 5/((x - 7)^2 + 49)]]
```

I got

> -\sin\left(\frac{5}{(x-7)^2+49}\right)

How can I get the result like this 
$\cos\left (\dfrac{\pi}{2} + \dfrac{5}{98 - 14 x + x^2}\right )$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Inactivate` instead of `HoldForm` to avoid evaluating `Cos`:

```
TeXForm[StandardForm[Inactivate[Cos[Pi/2 + 5/(Expand[(x - 7)^2 + 49])], Cos]]]
```

> $$\text{cos}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{5}{98-14 x+x^2}\right)$$

Now it is easy to change the brackets to parenthesis if you want, as well as the `Cos` function.

Comment: Your out put different to which I want. `Pi/2+` and `+Pi/2`.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 See my edit